# Ubuntu Touch OTA-10 apps stop when not in forground?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Im curious why apps stop when not in the forground (e.g. when I run `tail -f foo.txt` and i switch to my web browser the command is stopped when I switch back to the terminal).

Further, I'm curious how I can adjust this so they continuing running when not in the forground?

Comment: My guess is low memory issue, browser hogs ram, thus other apps in background get suspended

Comment: Which device do you use?

Comment: I'm using the Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu edition.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the application life-cycle on Ubuntu touch.

Only the currently focused app is allowed to be running and is entitled to use up as much of the system resources as it wishes. All unfocused apps get suspended and could potentially be killed when memory pressure get's too high.

tvoss wrote a detailed blog post on the life-cycle [here](https://samohtv.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/application-lifecycle-model-policies/) and it also links to some more in depth documentation on the if's and why's