# Make terminal app not stop applications when losing focus

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu touch terminal, when you run a command line application like `vim` or a long running shell script and you switch away to another app, the running application is stopped (like ctrl+z).

This is even more annoying when your application comes back but the terminall is messed up. And your application is revived in backgound. Or if you run a script an the script is stopped just because you have switched away. That script might be a server.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is supposed to be a bug report as there doesn't seem to be a question. If so please report it here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-terminal-app/+filebug?no_redirect

Or see http://askubuntu.com/q/778814/392342 about why the app is being suspended if you are wondering why

Comment: @DanielChapman . turns out to be a little bit of both. And a little bit more. I guess the question remains: Can i as a user/administrator of a device _bless_ an application so it will run in background and not be killed?

Comment: You can bless applications to have a lifecycle exemption by fiddling with gsettings but i can't recall how. it's alot easier to just use ubuntu touch tweak tool from the open store https://open.uappexplorer.com which you can select which apps you want to allow to run in the background

Answer (score 3):

You can change terminal lifecycle by running these command.

1. Find out which apps are supposed not to be suspended:

   ```
   gsettings get com.canonical.qtmir lifecycle-exempt-appids
   ```

   For me this command returns `['com.ubuntu.music']`
2. Add terminal app to this list

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.qtmir lifecycle-exempt-appids "['com.ubuntu.music', 'com.ubuntu.terminal']"
   ```

   Now terminal shouldn't be stopped anymore.

This solution from "[VLC running in the Terminal App on Ubuntu Touch has play/pause/skip controls in the sound indicator](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/3jlxb5/vlc_running_in_the_terminal_app_on_ubuntu_touch/)" on reddit.

Comment: made an error - please ignore thsi comment

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Daniel for the pointer.

The answer is:

Go to open.uappexplorer.com and download the openstore click package and install it.

If you cannot find your new open store app restart or search for it the apps scope.

From open store app install UT Tweak Tool.

Again, if the app is not in the scope, then search for it, restart or you can install an app from the normal app store. (this looks like a minor bug that the apps scope is not refreshed)

In UT Tweak Tool, go in the upper left menu and choose "apps scopes". There you can search for your app that you want to bless and activate "prevent app suspension".

Done.